# Manipulating dates momentjs in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, datepicker, momentjs

Auto-filling other date-fields based one the first one.

**1.** I have array of 12 indexes "listOfPaysIndexes", I am using this array to iterate through her and render 12 DateInput fields.

**2.** You can click on each of this fields and pick Date.

**3.** When you pick date in first DateInput all the others DateInputs should be auto-filled with the next month.

**Current behaviour is:** that when you pick firstDate you get same Date on all other fields.

**Expected behaviour is:** that when you pick firstDate every next filed get the next mounth date auto-fielled.

- Problem is when I choose 6 November 2018
  I get in first field 6 Nov, and in the all others fields I get 6 December 2018.
- But there should continue switching to the next mounths and displying next months dates.
- I think this line of code is problem:  return firstDate.add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY')

Code sample:

```
fillingDatesArray = (data, values, periodType, periodLength) => {
  let listOfPaysIndexes = []
  listOfPaysIndexes = This array have 12 indexes

if (periodType === 'monthly') {
  values.ending_period_monthly = listOfPaysIndexes.map(value => {
    let firstDate = new Date(data.value)
    return firstDate.add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
  })
}
```

Here is screenshot of that DateInputs: 
[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Liam Problem is cus if I choose 6 November 2018, I get in first field 6 Nov, and in the all others fields I get 6 December 2018. 
But there should continue switching to the next mounths. 
this line of code is problem:  return firstDate.add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: this problem is combination of react DOM, event listener, event handler. You only posted event handler. can you post snippet for react DOM and event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cloning your moment date in the `map` so each value is not the same reference to the same `moment object`:

```
let firstDate = moment(data.value)
...
return firstDate.clone().add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

instead of:

```
return firstDate.add(1, 'months').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```